# C: Program asking for user input even when input file is given as an argument

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, stdin, fopen

My program needs to take in a file input, and if one is not given, it needs to consider user input as its input.

When I feed an input file into the program like so:

```
./sim < ex1_in
```

everything works as it should!

However, when I specify an input file as a file argument, like so:

```
./sim ex1_in
```

the program looks for user input instead.

This is the part of the code that handles input and file arguments:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv []) {    

    if (argc > 3) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error: Too many arguments.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* check file */
        fprintf (stderr, "Error: File Open Failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 2;
    }    

    //Initializing array of 256 unsigned chars
    unsigned char binary[256]; 
    int i = 0; 
    unsigned char c;
    int count2 = 0; 


    //populate the 256 byte char array from stdin
    while (count2 < SIZE) {
        c=getchar();
        binary[i] = c;
        i++;
        count2++;                   
    }
```

So far, I've identified this `while` loop as a problem area as when I comment it out, the unwanted behavior doesn't happen. But I'm not sure why that is.

Later in the `main` method, the file is closed:

```
if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */
```

Another pertinent thing:

```
#define SIZE 256
```

Comment: You `fopen`, but I don't think `getchar` knows about your `fp` pointer. Other functions would be better.

Comment: You should use the `SIZE` macro in the declaration of `binary`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getchar()` reads from `stdin`, but you have to do all your input from `fp`. Change `getchar()` to `getc(fp)`.

`getchar()` is basically just short for `getc(stdin)`.

Another way to do this is to connect `stdin` to the file, instead of using another variable.

```
if (argc > 1) {
    freopen(argv[1], "r", stdin);
}
```

Comment: And maybe check argc and assign fp stdin if needed.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks! I was wondering if that's what I needed to do but felt that ...fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin; would mean that I didn't need to do that.

Comment: Why would you think that? A program can open files and still read from stdin.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I was adding that to the answer while you commented.

Comment: @Barmar if I were to use your second suggested method, would I need to use getchar() instead of getc(fp) as now stdin would be connected to the file?

Comment: If you use the second method, there is no `fp`. You just read from `stdin` just like normal.